# place transparent image over non-transparent image

Tags: php

I crop an uploaded image ($image) to a fixed size.

```
$new = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagealphablending($new, false);
imagesavealpha($new, true);
imagecopyresampled($new, $image, 0, 0, $x, $y, $width, $height, $width, $height);
```

I read that imagealphablending and imagesavealpha should be set like that. $image is not transparent.

```
$cover = imagecreatefrompng('../img/magazine2.png');
imagealphablending($cover, false);
imagesavealpha($cover, true);
```

Is the image that should be placed on top, and I read that it should have those settings.
both $new and $cover are now the exact same size.

And then I copy $cover over $new, which should be shown because $cover is transparent

```
imagecopy($new, $cover, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);
```

But it's placed on $new without transparency, what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

the only thing that had to be done was this:

```
imagealphablending($new, true);
```

no

```
imagealphablending($new, false);
imagesavealpha($new, true);
```

or

```
imagealphablending($cover, false);
imagesavealpha($cover, true);
```